# Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:references]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two queries, I need an `or` between them, i.e. I want results that are returned by either the first or the second query.

First query is a simple `where()` which gets all available items.

```
@items = @items.where(available: true)
```

Second includes a `join()` and gives the current user's items.

```
@items =
  @items
  .joins(:orders)
  .where(orders: { user_id: current_user.id})
```

I tried to combine these with Rails' `or()` method in various forms, including:

```
@items =
  @items
  .joins(:orders)
  .where(orders: { user_id: current_user.id})
  .or(
    @items
    .joins(:orders)
    .where(available: true)
  )
```

But I keep running into this error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:references]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is a [known issue about it on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24055).

According to [this comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24055#issuecomment-228099231) you might want to override the [`structurally_incompatible_values_for_or`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b18f2fe96debdcd0744f99101d1a1e0d42c41eaa/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L1190) to overcome the issue:

```
def structurally_incompatible_values_for_or(other)
  Relation::SINGLE_VALUE_METHODS.reject { |m| send("#{m}_value") == other.send("#{m}_value") } +
    (Relation::MULTI_VALUE_METHODS - [:eager_load, :references, :extending]).reject { |m| send("#{m}_values") == other.send("#{m}_values") } +
    (Relation::CLAUSE_METHODS - [:having, :where]).reject { |m| send("#{m}_clause") == other.send("#{m}_clause") }
end
```

Also there is always an option to use SQL:

```
@items
  .joins(:orders)
  .where("orders.user_id = ? OR items.available = true", current_user.id)
```

Comment: Went with SQL queries instead. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Andrey Should have referred to my answer instead of editing yours and adding the same. Anyway, +1 for the first solution.

Comment: @RSB i was going to start with sql part, than googled error message and found a github issue. After all I still decided to add my initial thought, since it's the less code to make it work.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko  Where to add structurally_incompatible_values_for_or method in rails application?

Answer (score 25):

Hacky workaround: do all your `.joins` after the `.or`. This hides the offending `.joins` from the checker. That is, convert the code in the original question to...

```rb
@items =
  @items
  .where(orders: { user_id: current_user.id})
  .or(
    @items
    .where(available: true)
  )
  .joins(:orders) # sneaky, but works!
```

More generally, the following two lines will both fail

```rb
A.joins(:b).where(bs: b_query).or(A.where(query))  # error!
```

```rb
A.where(query).or(A.joins(:b).where(bs: b_query))  # error!
```

but rearrange as follows, and you can evade the checker:

```rb
A.where(query).or(A.where(bs: b_query)).joins(:b)  # works
```

This works because all the checking happens inside the `.or()` method. It's blissfully unaware of shennanigans on its downstream results.

One downside of course is it doesn't read as nicely.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. This really _should_ be the answer.

Comment: Fixed for me to. Thanks ! joins and includes must be added after or. Can someone explain why, if this works, rails does not accept us to add it before 'or' ?

Comment: @LiKaZ for `joins`, I don't think any good reason. In fact, after rails 6.1.3 I think you you can put the `.joins` before the `.or`, and I know for fact you can put `.includes` before the `.or`. 

As for why this exists in the first place... Rails has to restrict certain operations like `.limit` or `.distinct`, as allowing these before `.or` would be untranslatable to sql. (What would it mean to `.or` together two clauses with different `.limit`s?)

Longer explanation of all cases here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24055#issuecomment-793274937

Comment: @nar8789 thanks for these explainations. I will upgrade my Rails 6.0 application to 6.1.3 soon !

Comment: Would have been interesting to know what the generated SQL looked like for your answer, because more than working it's important it does the right thing.

Comment: @NunoCosta Sure thing! here's a (partially redacted) test I just ran at the console: `puts A.where(id: 1).or(A.where(bs: { id: 1 })).joins(:b).to_sql` yields `SELECT "as".* FROM "as" INNER JOIN "bs" ON "bs"."id" = "as"."b_id" WHERE ("as"."id" = 1 OR "bs"."id" = 1)`. This looks like good SQL to me. This did reveal an error in pluralization in my original examples. I'll update that now.

Answer (score 22):

You can write the query in this good old way to avoid error

```
@items = @items.joins(:orders).where("items.available = ? OR orders.user_id = ?", true, current_user.id)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, however the code was defined in a different place and was very difficult to change directly.

```
# I can't change "p"
p = Post.where('1 = 1').distinct # this could also be a join
```

And I needed to add an `or` statement to it

```
p.or(Post.where('2 = 2'))
```

The following code won't raise an error, because it has `distinct` like the initial relationship.

```
p.or(Post.where('2 = 2').distinct)
```

The problem with it it that it only works as long as you know the relationship. It may or not have a `join`, or `distinct`.

This works regardless of what the relationship is:

```
p.or(p.unscope(:where).where('2 = 2'))
=> SELECT DISTINCT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE ((1 = 1) OR (2 = 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when you try to combine two multi-active records of the same type, but one of them has a joins value or an includes value, or in your case a reference value, that the other does not.
Therefore we need to match the values between them, and I found a general way to do this without knowing the actual values in advance.

```
items_1 = @items.joins(:orders)
                .where(orders: { user_id: current_user.id})

items_2 = @items.where(available: true)
                .joins(items_1.joins_values)
                .includes(items_1.includes_values)
                .references(items_1.references_values)

@items = items_1.or(items_2)
```

Answer (score -1):

just solve it!

```
  def exec_or_statement(q1, q2)
    klass = q1.klass
    key = klass.primary_key

    query_wrapper_1 = {}
    query_wrapper_1[key] = q1

    query_wrapper_2 = {}
    query_wrapper_2[key] = q2

    klass.where(query_wrapper_1).or(klass.where(query_wrapper_2))
  end

  query_1 = @items.where(available: true)

  query_2 =
    @items
    .joins(:orders)
    .where(orders: { user_id: current_user.id})
  
  exec_or_statement(query_1, query_2)
```