# ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two scopes in a model.  Both utilize `joins`.  It appears that `joins` is incompatible with the Rails 5 or query.

Example:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :comments

  scope :with_comment_likes, -> {joins(:comments).merge(Comment.some_scope_on_comment)}
  scope :some_other_comment_merge_scope, -> {joins(:comments).merge(Comment.other_scope)}

  scope :aggregate_or_scope, -> {with_comment_likes.or(some_other_comment_merge_scope)}
end

Blog.aggregate_or_scope
```

Returned error:

```
ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. 
Incompatible values: [:joins]
```

Any suggestions for how to get around this?  I'm stumped. I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742078/relation-passed-to-or-must-be-structurally-compatible-incompatible-values-r), but I was having trouble applying it.

Comment: what is the version of Rails are you using exactly? can't reproduce this error on 5.1.4 (maybe it was already fixed)

Comment: I am confident it was a rails version prior to 5.1.0.

Comment: This still happens in rails 6.

Answer (score 3):

Two years late to the party but here is the way you could accomplish this:

```rb
class Blog < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :comments

  scope :aggregate_or_scope, lambda {
    joins(:comments).merge(
      Comment.some_scope_on_comment.or(Comment.other_scope)
    )
  }
end

Blog.aggregate_or_scope
```

The difference here is that you are only joining once and the `or` is on the `Comment` query being merged which does not have any `joins`, rather than the `Blog` query which does.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue, and the solution I found out was:

`def matching_one_or_two
  temp = Model.matching_one + Model.matching_two
  Model.where('id in (?)',temp.map(&:id))
end`

Certainly not the world's greatest performance, but it results in an ActiveRecord::Relation object pointing at the 'OR' results.

Comment: At least use `pluck(:id)` on that! If, for example, you want to get a count, you're going to be instantiating every single record you're counting (which could be thousands), discarding them, and _then_ creating the count query

Answer (score 0):

After much trails. Here is the working solution:

```
def self.aggregate_or_scope
  with_comment_likes_id = with_comment_likes.pluck(:id)
  some_other_comment_merge_scope_id = some_other_comment_merge_scope.pluck(:id)
  all_ids = with_comment_likes_id.concat(some_other_comment_merge_scope_id)
  
  Blog.where(id: all_ids)
end
```