# Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this error message
`Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]`

in my user model: `has_many :orders`

in my order model: `belongs_to :user,  optional: true`

How I am supposed to write my query to have either the users' names and the order id in the same search input?

```
def filter_orders
  return if params[:query].blank?
  @orders = Order.joins(:user).where('lower(users.first_name) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%")
  .or(Order.joins(:user).where('lower(users.last_name) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%"))
  .or(Order.where(id: "#{params[:query][:keyword]}.to_i"))
end
```

Comment: Can you post more code? Specifically the User and Order models?

Comment: I added the relationship :)

Answer (score 1):

It sound like this is a know [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24055) with `.or`. Try using SQL or you can override `.or` as seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40742512/10987825

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when you try to combine two multi-active records of the same type, but one of them has a reference value or an includes value, or in your case a joins value, that the other does not.
Therefore we need to match the values between them, and I found a general way to do this without knowing the actual values in advance.

```
def filter_orders
  return if params[:query].blank?

  orders_1 = Order.joins(:user).where('lower(users.first_name) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%")
  
  orders_2 = Order.joins(:user).where('lower(users.last_name) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%")

  orders_3 = Order.where(id: "#{params[:query][:keyword]}.to_i")

  joind_orders = orders_1.or(
                         orders_2
                               .joins(orders_1.joins_values)
                               .includes(orders_1.includes_values)
                               .references(orders_1.references_values)
                   )

  @orders = joind_orders.or(
                         orders_3
                               .joins(joind_orders.joins_values)
                               .includes(joind_orders.includes_values)
                               .references(joind_orders.references_values)
                   )

end
```