# How to do two joins and execute a single active record query using ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using MySQL and I'm trying to create a couple of scopes to find a User based on a set of conversations, users and conversations have a polymorphic association that allows the user to author and receives conversations.

The "with_conversations" scope is doing what I want, however, it's not very efficient, I'm having trouble making it execute a single query instead of the addition 2 arrays, which triggers 2 separate queries.

```
class User 

  scope :with_received_conversations, -> (conversations) { joins(:received_conversations).where(conversations: { id: conversations, receiver_type: "User" }) }
  scope :with_authored_conversations, -> (conversations) { joins(:authored_conversations).where(conversations: { id: conversations, author_type: "User" }) }
  scope :with_conversations,          -> (conversations) { with_authored_conversations(conversations) | with_received_conversations(conversations) }

end
```

I attempted using the "or()" active record function but it returns the following error:

```
*** ArgumentError Exception: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]

nil
```

Comment: using || instead of | can return an empty array when the authored_conversations are empty, but the received conversations are not. this is an example of this occurring in one of my tests.

`with_received_conversations(conversations) || with_authored_conversations(conversations) `

`#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: Would you mind adding your models? And the db/schema file if needed?

Comment: `scope` is just syntactic sugar for declaring class methods. Its best used for simple one-liners (that actually fit on a normal line). Use normal class method definition on these monsters for better readability.

Comment: This might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686920/activerecord-query-union

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment so I am sorry for creating an answer.  I think that this post is helpful.

[Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:references]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742078/relation-passed-to-or-must-be-structurally-compatible-incompatible-values-r)